# Voice recognition/dictation for Android

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

Good day,

I am in the early stages of building a cooking/recipe app. The main purpose of the app is to be able to follow and traverse recipes using voice dictation. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to implement these features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

call the system's built-in Speech Recognizer activity to obtain speech input from users. This is useful to obtain input from users and then process it, such as doing a search or sending it as a message.

In your app, you call startActivityForResult() using the ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH action. This starts the speech recognition activity, and you can then handle the result in onActivityResult().

```
private static final int SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE = 0;

// Create an intent that can start the Speech Recognizer activity
private void displaySpeechRecognizer() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
// Start the activity, the intent will be populated with the speech text
    startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE);
}

// This callback is invoked when the Speech Recognizer returns.
// This is where you process the intent and extract the speech text from the intent.
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SPEECH_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        List<String> results = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        String spokenText = results.get(0);
        // Do something with spokenText
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```